# Uploading files with different extensions with ajax and flask

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using flask to upload files with ajax the code is:

```
app = Flask(name) 
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True 
CORS(app) 
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

@app.route("/upload//<element_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ws_product_upload(element_id):
    print("Starting....")
    if request.is_xhr:
        print("xhr request received")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        process_inmemory( element_id, file=f)
        print("file received by post")
        if request.is_xhr:
            print("xhr request received inside post")
            return json.dumps({'result': True})
        return json.dumps({'result': True})
    return 'file uploaded needs a post call'
```

When I send an image, everything works ok, but with a simple txt file, fails.

I have tried:

```
app.config["UPLOADED_FILES_ALLOW"] = ['.txt']  # with [] and with out with . and without and nothin
app.config["UPLOADED_FILES_DENY"] = 'exe'
```

I want to do it with almost all mime types and extensions

I'm using nginx + gunicorn (don't know if it is relevant)

Witch is the way to do it properly

Comment: You have to show us your complete code, incl. configuration. Also, do you use the extension `Flask-Uploads`? Which versions? I am curious, as I cannot find `UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS` in the source-code of `Flask-Uploads`.

Comment: I'm also curious, I try to find it all packages in dist-packages and... nothing.  I have very few lines of code related with flask, app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True CORS(app) app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024, I'm adding to the code, but I think that it is not relevant. @J.G. And not, I'm not using flask-upload,

Comment: The `process_inmemory` function is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the upload, the problem was chrome and cors, I don't understand why but uploading images it works.

The solution is to put a cors decorator **cross_origin** before the functions like this one:

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/upload//<element_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True, origins=["https://blabla.com","http://blabla:4202"])
def ws_product_upload(element_id):
    print("Starting....")
    if request.is_xhr:
        print("xhr request received")
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 1):

So - this is some guess work :-)

"UPLOADED_FILES_ALLOW" and "UPLOADED_FILES_DENY" are two env variable names used in `Flask-Uploads` - that's why I asked whether you use it, but you do not.

'UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS' is an environment variable which is used in Miguel Grinberg's mega tutorial - see here https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask

I assume you followed the tutorial of Miguel Grinberg, and in your - as of now - hidden `process_inmemory` function you do something similar as in the tutorial, e.g. a check like `if file_ext not in current_app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:`.

That is actually the only reasonable explanation - until you really show us your complete code.

Comment: Not really, the process_inmemory actually calculate a hash of the file and save it, nothing related with flask or anything else. I didn't use that tutorial. And UPLOAD_EXTENSION only apeears were i wrote. As it works with images i started to search about extensions or types, and get both configurations in different places.  Look print("Starting....") It does not get printed off the extension is not in the list. So weird. I also check the app.py of flask package and nothing,

Comment: I went out of office, I'll get back on this tomorrow and make more test and will get back here

Comment: I have to say sorry, it still not working with "UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS" another request, in the console, confuse me :( so it is unsolved, and as expected, "UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS" does nothing. I'm going to change the Question, and also comment the process_inmemory to avoid (an un probably) side effects

Comment: Solved: I was wrong, I was looking in a wrong direction, because uploading images works. The problem is CORS!!!!! But I can't understand why it works with images and not with the other files.

Comment: Oh wow, this is surprising - thanks for the update! And great you could resolve it on your own!